# Proxy https://flywaydb.org/repo repository using Nexus OSS?

Tags: sbt, nexus, flyway

I'm trying to proxy https://flywaydb.org/repo using Nexus Repository OSS v2.13.0 because we rely on flyway-sbt sbt plugin.

I can download the plugin fine if I add

```
resolvers += "Flyway" at "https://flywaydb.org/repo"
```

to plugins.sbt

But we want to proxy the artefacts using a local Nexus repository because we don't want our builds to depend on a server that is outside our control.

However when I add the server to Nexus (using Maven2 as provider and format) Nexus is unable to proxy artefacts and I get following error in logs:

```
[proxy-3-thread-5] admin org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.maven2.M2Repository - Remote peer of proxy repository "flywaydb.org" [id=flywaydb.org] threw a org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.ItemNotFoundException exception. Auto-blocking this repository to prevent further connection-leaks and known-to-fail outbound connections until administrator fixes the problems, or Nexus detects remote repository as healthy. - Cause(s): Remote peer of repository M2Repository(id=flywaydb.org) detected as unavailable.
```

I would be happy to hear if somebody was able to get this working. We successfully proxy several other external repositories.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that we ran Nexus using an old Java 6 version. Java threw an exception which seems to be related to SSL communication. Running Nexus using Java 8 solved the problem for us.